# How to generate GraphQL Types from Entity Framework Models

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, graphql, graphql-js

Is there a tool to generate GraphQL types from the models of Entity Framework?

Comment: while looking for the same answer, I ran across; https://github.com/ckimes89/graphql-net

Comment: @KenL, please post it as an answer so we can give you votes for it